Ansible Playbook failing on AWX Execution Environment for Docker
I'm using the following builder for my Execution Environment:
https://github.com/kurokobo/awx-on-k3s/tree/main/builder
This is my "dependencies/requirements.yml"
collections:
  - name: community.general
    version: 8.6.0
    source: https://galaxy.ansible.com
  - name: community.docker
    version: 3.9.0
    source: https://galaxy.ansible.com
  - name: ansible.posix
    version: 1.5.4
    source: https://galaxy.ansible.com
  - name: community.library_inventory_filtering_v1
    version: 1.0.1
    source: https://galaxy.ansible.com

This is in my "dependencies/requirements.txt"
passlib
requests
paramiko
pyOpenSSL

When the task for "docker_login" executes, the following error happens
exception: |
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/ansible_docker_login_payload_rls1p2u3/ansible_docker_login_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/module_utils/_api/_import_helper.py", line 24, in <module>
      from requests import Session  # noqa: F401, pylint: disable=unused-import
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
msg: >-
  Failed to import the required Python library (requests) on
  <my server here>'s Python /usr/libexec/platform-python. Please
  read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If
  the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python
  interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter

I verified that the AWX EE does have "requests" module installed as well as Python 3.11.7. When I update my task and define the ansible_python_interpreter it then fails not able to find Python. All my other AWX EE's work fine that require dependencies. It's just the community.docker one.
NOTE:
I am on AWX 24.3.1

When the AWX job runs, the EE pod spins up in Kubernetes and it uses the Docker image to build the pod/s. So you're trying to login to Docker from inside of a K8s pod (the EE)...is that intentional? I don't think you can run Docker from inside of K8s.
